# Why is GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.init() invisible?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to use a `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` to hook up a custom `UserDetailsService` to the [`AuthserverApplication.java`](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/java/demo/AuthserverApplication.java) root class of [this sample Spring Boot OAuth2 sample app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2).

The [Spring OAuth2 Developer Guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html#grant-types) says to use a `GobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` to hook up the `UserDetailsService`.  And [I modified code from the example in this blog post](http://ryanjbaxter.com/2015/01/06/securing-rest-apis-with-spring-boot/).

However, when I try to launch the modified `authserver` app using `mvn spring-boot:run`, the following root error is reported:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  
demo.AuthserverApplication$WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43683c11.<init>()
```

The complete log from the `mvn spring-boot:run` including the full stack trace of the error message [can be read at a file sharing site by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/fBM6hYgwVi0i90a9lD2Z).

**I then read [the documentation for `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.html), and confirmed that there is an `init()` method.**

**What specific changes need to be made to the code below (or the other code in [the GitHub sample app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2)) in order to resolve this error and successfully hook up the custom `UserDetailsService` to the sample GitHub app?**

---

**REPRODUCING THE PROBLEM ON YOUR MACHINE:**

---

You can reproduce this problem on any machine within minutes by re-creating my steps as follows:

1.) Download the Spring Oauth2 sample apps onto your computer by typing:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/
```

2.) Navigate to `tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver`.  This is the app that is breaking.  When you type `mvn spring-boot:run` without making any changes, it should launch correctly.  But then make the following changes to re-create the problem:

3.) Added the following to `AuthserverApplication.java` to connect a custom `UserDetailsService`:

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Users users;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(users);
    }

}
```

4.) Add the following `Users.java` class to [the `demo` package of the `authserver` app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/java/demo), so that the `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` from **3** above points to a real custom `UserDetailsService`.  Note that I unhooked the JDBC so that there is no database dependency in this code sample:

```
package demo;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
class Users implements UserDetailsManager {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        String password;
        List<GrantedAuthority> auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER");
        if (username.equals("Samwise")) {
            auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_HOBBIT");
            password = "TheShire";
        }
        else if (username.equals("Frodo")){
            auth = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_HOBBIT");
            password = "MyRing";
        }
        else{throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username was not found. ");}
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, password, auth);
    }

    @Override
    public void createUser(UserDetails user) {// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(UserDetails user) {// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(String username) {// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void changePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean userExists(String username) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

The complete code of the modified `AuthserverApplication.java`, including the new `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` [can be found at a file sharing site by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/Xu2yl7qnvFWxzWuklp2N).

5.) Type `mvn spring-boot:run` to try to launch the `authserver` app.  This will trigger the `nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: demo.AuthserverApplication$WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43683c11.<init>()` error described above.

Comment: The first error is just because your `WebSecurityConfiguration`is not visible. You could add the `protected` keyword to fix that. In general it is probably better to keep you questions short and focused on a single problem.

Comment: I'm not so sure there is a single problem that anyone could latch on to here. If there was I'd be happy to answer a question. Anyway there are plenty of sample apps out there, and most people with problems find them helpful.

Comment: `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` is a Spring Security feature. If you want samples look in the Spring Security repos. Even in Spring Security OAuth you will find sample apps that override the default authentication manager. Spring Boot also has an extensive set of sample apps in its own repo with examples of doing the same thing. I'll transcribe the answer to the question about the "one single problem" from my first comment into an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is just because your `WebSecurityConfiguration` is not visible. You could add the `protected static` keywords to fix that.

Comment: Oops, forgot to say "protected static" (the constructor has to be visible, which is clear from the error message actually). This is really nothing to do with Spring Boot or Spring OAuth. If you have questions about features in those tools, please start new threads.

Comment: Adding `static` to make `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) @Configuration protected static class WebSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter { ...}` resolves this problem. And removing `static` from same recreates the problem. Thank you and +1 for answering. Please add the 9 line `WebSecurityConfiguration` to your developer guide so that others can avoid this problem. They will now be able to find this OP when they google this error, but they can avoid the error in the first place if you add it to the developer guide. Your stuff needs to work with the rest of Spring